# Algorithm for sorting unordered list to tree structure

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am looking for an algorithm to sort an unordered list of items into a tree structure, using the minimum number of "is child" comparison operations as possible.

A little background on my specific case, but I guess I am just looking for a generic sorting algorithm of a sort I have been unable to find (it is a hard search term to refine).

I have an unordered list of contours, which are simply lists of coordinates that describe closed polygons. I want to create a tree that represents the relationship between these contours, such that the outermost is the root, with each contour at the next level as children, and so forth. So a tree structure with zero-to-many children per node.

A key requirement of the algorithm is that tests to determine whether or not a contour is the child of another are kept to a minimum, as this operation is very expensive. Contours can (and often do) share many vertices, but should not intersect. These shared vertices usually arise where map limits are reached - picture a set of concentric semi circles against the straight edge of a map. The point-in-poly test is slow if I need to run through lots of point-on-lines before I get to a definitive answer.

Here's the algorithm I have come up with so far. It's pretty naive, no doubt, but it works. There are probably some heuristics that may help - a contour is only likely to be a child of another contour with a depth within a certain range, for example - but I want to nail the basic algorithm first. The first red flag is that it is exponential.

```
for each candidate_contour in all_contours
    for each contour in all_contours
        // note already contains means "is direct or indirect child of"
        if contour == candidate_contour or contour already contains(candidate_contour)
            continue
        else
            list contours_to_check
            contours_to_check.add(candidate_contour)

            contour parent_contour = candidate_contour.parent
            while (parent_contour != null)
                contours_to_check.add(parent_contour)
                parent_contour = parent_contour.parent

            for each possible_move_candidate in contours_to_check (REVERSE ITERATION)
                if possible_move_candidate is within contour
                    // moving a contour moves the contour and all of its children
                    move possible_move_candidate to direct child of contour
                    break
```

So that works - or at least it seems to - but it gets very slow with a non-trivial number of contours (think - several hundred, to possibly several thousand).

Is there a fundamentally better way to do this, or indeed - are there known algorithms that deal with exactly this? As mentioned before - the key in my case is to keep the "is contour within" comparisons to a minimum.

**Edit to add solution based on Jim's answer below - thanks Jim!**

**This is the first iteration - which produce good (10x) improvements. See below for iteration 2.**
This code versus my original algorithm is > 10x faster once the contour set becomes non-trivially big. See image below that is now sorted in a couple of seconds (v's 30 odd seconds prior), and rendered in order. I think there is room to further improve with some added heuristics - for example, now that the original list is sorted according to area, then each new candidate has to be a leaf node somewhere in the tree. The difficulty is determining which branches to traverse to test the existing leaves - if there are many branches/leaves, then it is probably still quicker to cut the search space down by examining the branches at the top.. something more to think about!

```
    public static iso_area sort_iso_areas(List<iso_area> areas, iso_area root)
    {
        if (areas.Count == 0)
            return null;

        areas.Sort(new iso_comparer_descending());

        foreach (iso_area area in areas)
        {
            if (root.children.Count == 0)
                root.children.Add(area);
            else
            {
                bool found_child = false;
                foreach (iso_area child in root.children)
                {
                    // check if this iso_area is within the child
                    // if it is, follow the children down to find the insertion position
                    if (child.try_add_child(area))
                    {
                        found_child = true;
                        break;
                    }   
                }
                if (!found_child)
                    root.children.Add(area);
            }
        }
        return root;
    }

    // try and add the provided child to this area
    // if it fits, try adding to a subsequent child
    // keep trying until failure - then add to the previous child in which it fitted
    bool try_add_child(iso_area area)
    {
        if (within(area))
        {
            // do a recursive search through all children
            foreach (iso_area child in children)
            {
                if (child.try_add_child(area))
                    return true;
            }
            area.move_to(this);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

[image: ordered contours]

**Iteration two - comparing against existing leaves only**

Following on from my earlier thought that new contours could only fit into existing leaves, it struck me that in fact this would be much quicker **as the poly in poly test would fail at the first bounds check for all leaves other than the target leaf.** The first solution involved traversing a branch to find the target where, by definition, each and every poly along the way would pass the bounds check, and involve a full poly-in-poly test until no further leaves were found.

Following Jim's comment and re-examination of the code - the second solution did not work, unfortunately. I'm wondering if there may still be some merit to looking at lower elements in the tree before the branches, as the poly-in-poly test should fail quickly, and you know that if you find a leaf that accepts the candidate, there are no more polys that need to be examined..

**Iteration two revisited**

Although it is not the case that contours can **only** fit into leaves, it is the case that they almost always do - and also that they will usually fit into a recent predecessor in the ordered list of contours. This final updated code is the fastest yet, and ditches the tree traversal completely. It simply walks backwards through the recent larger polygons and tries each - polys from other branches will likely fail the poly-in-poly test at the bounds check, and the first poly found that surrounds the candidate poly has to be the immediate parent, due to the prior sorting of the list. This code brings the sorting down into the millisecond range again and is about 5x faster than the tree traversal (significant speed improvements were also made to the poly-in-poly test which accounts for the rest of the speed-up). The root is now taken from the sorted list of areas. Note that I now supply a root in the list that I **know** encompasses all the contours (bounding box of all).

Thanks for the help - and Jim in particular - for helping me think about this problem. The key really was the original sorting of the contours into a list in which it was guaranteed that no contour could be a child of a later contour in the list.

```
public static iso_area sort_iso_areas(List<iso_area> areas)
    {
        if (areas.Count == 0)
            return null;

        areas.Sort(new iso_comparer_descending());

        for (int i = 0; i < areas.Count; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j)
            {
                if (areas[j].try_add_child(areas[i]))
                    break;    
            }              
        }
        return areas[0];
    }
```

My original attempt: **133 s**
Iteration 1 (traverse branch to find leaf): **9s**
Iteration 2 (walk backwards through contours in ascending size order): 25ms (with other pt-in-poly improvements also).

Comment: Virtually every serious sorting implementation allows you to supply your own comparison routine. Why don't you just use these, with "is child of" as comparision?

Comment: I believe your algorithm is O(n^2). You may want to try heapsort, which is O(nlogn).

Comment: @delnan - my results need to be in a tree structure - there could be many direct children of any particular contour. Do you know of a sort routine that can handle this?

Comment: @Matt Once the list is sorted, you can re-construct the tree using a linear number of "is *direct* child of" queries.

Comment: @delnan - I'll think about this more in the morning, but - imagine a large circle (1), with 2 smaller circles inside (2,3), and inside them, 4 and 5 respectively. To sort these into a list, you would get 1, 2, 3, then 4 is within 2, but not within 3. But 3 is not within 4 - so there is no natural linear ordering that would satisfy a sort algorithm. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't understand the leaves-only logic. The code you posted shouldn't work. In the first case, you don't add the first node to the leaves list, so any children of that node will be added at the root level. More importantly, your code as posted removes a node from the leaves list as soon as it contains a single child. So no node can have more than one child? That doesn't appear to be correct, based on the picture you posted. Are you certain that your Iteration 2 generates the same tree as Iteration 1?

Comment: Jim - you are correct. The second solution is total nonsense, d'oh! I will amend. It does actually provide a very similar (but incorrect) solution just by virtue of the fact that the areas are already ordered - I think I was getting a bit overexcited :) It is true of course that any poly can go into any other - they do not need to be leaves at all (although they usually are - so I do wonder if there might be something in this heuristic, somehwhere??). I will amend my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did something similar a while back by first sorting by area.

If polygon B is contained within polygon A, then the bounding box for polygon A has to be larger than the bounding box for polygon B. More to the point, if you specify the bounding box as `((x1, y1), (x2, y2))`, then:

```
A.x1 < B.x1
A.y1 < B.y1
A.x2 > B.x2
A.y2 > B.y2
```

(Those relationships might be `<=` and `>=` if polygons can share edges or vertices.)

So the first thing you should do is compute the bounding boxes and sort the polygons by bounding box area, descending (so the largest is first).

Create a structure that is essentially a polygon and a list of its children:

```
PolygonNode
{
    Polygon poly
    PolygonNode[] Children
}
```

So you start out with your polygons sorted by bounding box area, descending, and an initially empty list of `PolygonNode` structures:

```
Polygon[] sortedPolygons
PolygonNode[] theTree
```

Now, starting from the first member of `sortedPolygons`, which is the polygon with the largest area, check to see if it's a child of any of the top-level members of `theTree`. If it's not, add the polygon to the `theTree`. The bounding boxes help here because you don't have to do the full polygon-in-polygon test if the bounding box test fails.

If it *is* a child of a node, then check to see if it's a child of one of that node's children, and follow the child chain down until you find the insertion spot.

Repeat that for every polygon in `sortedPolygons`.

*Worst case*, that algorithm is O(n^2), which will happen if there are no parent/child relationships. But assuming that there are many nested parent/child relationships, the search space gets cut down very quickly.

You can probably speed it up somewhat by ordering the `theTree` list and the child nodes lists by position. You could then use a binary search to more quickly locate the potential parent for a polygon. Doing so complicates things a little bit, but it might be worthwhile if you have a lot of top-level polygons. I wouldn't add that optimization on the first cut, though. It's quite possible that the version I outlined using sequential search will be plenty fast enough.

### Edit

Understanding the nature of the data helps. I didn't realize when I wrote my original response that your typical case is that given the sorted list of polygons, the normal case is that `p[i]` is a child of `p[i-1]`, which is a child of `p[i-2]`, etc. Your comments indicate that it's not *always* the case, but it is very often.

Given that, perhaps you should make a simple modification to your implementation so that you save the last polygon and check it first rather than starting in with the tree. So your loop looks something like this:

```
    iso_area last_area = null;    // <============
    foreach (iso_area area in areas)
    {
        if (root.children.Count == 0)
            root.children.Add(area);
        else if (!last_area.try_add_child(area))  // <=======
        {
            bool found_child = false;
            foreach (iso_area child in root.children)
            {
                // check if this iso_area is within the child
                // if it is, follow the children down to find the insertion position
                if (child.try_add_child(area))
                {
                    found_child = true;
                    break;
                }   
            }
            if (!found_child)
                root.children.Add(area);
        }
        last_area = area;      // <============
    }
    return root;
```

If the data is as you said, then this optimization should help quite a bit because it eliminates a bunch of searching through the tree.

Comment: Thanks Jim - this looks good at first glance, in that it seems to reduce the problem to a linear solution. I do use bounding boxes already as the first test in the poly-in-poly, but hadn't thought about sorting by area. I have just tried a rough implementation but the problem is that some polys do have the same bounding boxes, and if the initial sort puts them in the wrong order, there is no chance to correct this error (contours already in the tree never get the chance to be children of subsequent polys). I'll see how hard it is to combat this (common) edge case and get back to you.

Comment: Wouldn't the algorithm also become O(n²) if the shapes are all inside of each other? In other words, if every node ends up having just 1 child?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Yes. There are degenerate cases. In the data I had, however, the degenerate cases never occurred and this approach helped quite a bit.

Comment: @Matt: That will be a problem if A contains B and they both have the same bounding box, but the sort puts them in the wrong order. You could have your sort comparison check for equal bounding boxes and do the poly-in-poly test in that case so that they're ordered correctly.

Comment: Thanks Jim - I have updated my question with a solution based on your answer, which shows a marked (real world) performance improvement over my original algorithm.

Comment: @Jim - that's a good thought, and I had a similar one myself (not tried yet). In the example though, it probably wouldn't be that very-last inserted node very often (there are many similar sized contours within others). What is "very-often-but-not-always" the case is that the candidate area will fit into a leaf node. That fact, coupled with the very quick poly-in-poly test (bounds check) against disjoint leaves means that there probably **is** a good case to check all leaves first, and then revert to the original algorithm if that fails. I just need to implement it properly now :)

Comment: @Matt: That could work well as long as the list of leaves isn't very large. And removing an item from a linear list is kind of expensive. Since it doesn't need to be ordered, you can optimize the removal by replacing the removed item with the last, and decrementing the count. Otherwise, removing is an O(n) operation, where n is the number of leaves in the list.

Comment: @Jim - updated with new version that simply walks backwards through the sorted list and tries each. For my use-cases, this is the fastest by far, and also very simple. I appreciate your insights!

Comment: @Matt: Good insight. Congrats on getting a 5,000% increase in speed over your original. If this answer solved your problem, I'd appreciate you clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive approach works well when dealing with trees. The following algorithm ought to be O(N log(N)) in cases where your shapes are distributed fairly evenly. It becomes O(N²) worse-case if your shapes are all concentric in one long tunnel-like distribution.

```
boolean tryAddToNode(Node possibleParent, Node toAdd)
{
    if not toAdd.isChildOf(possibleParent)
        return false
    for each child in possibleParent.children
        if(tryAddToNode(child, toAdd))
             return true
    // not a child of any of my children, but
    // it is a child of me.
    possibleParent.children.add(toAdd)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stripling - I will implement and time this in the morning. The only potential issue I can see is that "one long tunnel-like distribution" is the (ideal) central case - so it may not end up being any quicker than my current method. I'll let you know.

Comment: @Matt: So your ideal case is to have all of the shapes inside one another like a bunch of babushka dolls? I'll think about this some more tonight, and see if I can suggest any optimizations. Can you provide any more information? Are your coordinates bounded? What's the degree of precision on them?

Comment: @Matt: Upon reflection, I realized that this solution will only work if the objects are being added to the tree from largest to smallest, to ensure that parent nodes are always present before you try to add their child nodes. Also, I haven't been able to think of any other ways to reduce the number of calls to isChildOf, but I've thought of a lot of ways you could probably reduce the cost of those checks--have you spent much time thinking in that direction?

Comment: "ideal case" is probably a bit strong, but if you think of depths in a lake, then you will get the idea. A very simple topography might have a small number of long nests. I have gone with Jim's solution but I appreciate your time!